# Excel 2010 : Tracking dates

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am a novice at the functions in Excel.

I have a tracking sheet on which I need to record a variable due date. The variable factor is a date that is either 180 or 150 days from the original date, depending on when the start date is before or after 6/1/2017.

So in one column I have a list of various dates. In the second column, the desired result is 150 or 180 days from that date, depending on whether the original date is 6/1/2017 and after or before.

[image: Sample of date columns]

Answer (score 2):

Use in B2 under Date2:

```
=IF(A2<DATEVALUE("06-01-2017"),A2+180,A2+150)
```

A2 is the first date under Date1
If will test A2 before 06-01-2017
True is A2+180
False is A2+150
Format B2 as Date and drag it down

Comment: Thank you, Yass. This is perfect ... it does exactly what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: This looks like what I am trying to do ... I put it in a worksheet and then tried changing the first column dates to before 01-Jun and after 01-Jun. The result is not quite right ... it gives me the "A2+150" result even if I enter a date prior to 01-Jun. For example, if I enter a date of 02-Feb, it should add 180 days in the result. It actually gives me 02-Jul, which is 150 days.

Comment: format the date properly

Comment: You can use "02-02-2017"

Answer (score 1):

=IF(A2-DATEVALUE("1-JUN-17")>0,A2+150,A2+180)

Type this in the first cell under Date 2, changing the cell reference A2, if necessary, to point to the first cell under Date 1. Then fill down.

Depending on how you want to treat the date 1-Jun-17, the datevalue might need to be >=0 instead of >0.

The Date 2 column must be formatted as dates.

Use Excel Help to search for and learn about the IF() function, date arithmetic, and the DATEVALUE() function

PS. see this link about what to do next: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you, Bandersnatch. This does seem to work the way I am trying to make it work. It gives me the correct results in my testing so far. Much appreciate the help. Before posting my question, I did try and search Excel and the IF() function but got totally lost ... like I said, I'm a novice! So I thank you for your help.